# Address Label Printing without Windows Address Book

Tags: printing, address-book, label

In the past I've maintained my address book using the built-in Address Book utility that came with Windows.  Once each year, I would import my Address Book (.WAB) file into Outlook 2003/XP.  (I don't use Outlook for email.)  Then I would use the Mail Merge feature in Word 2003/XP to make and print address labels on standard Avery label sheets to simplify address of my Christmas cards.

Since I'm now using Windows 7, and the familiar Address Book utility is no longer available, how can I print my address labels?  I have both Windows Address Book (.WAB) and Comma-Separated Values (.CSV) files that contain my address book data.  So, I guess I need to know two things:

1. Which program or utility (preferably free) can I use to print my address labels.
2. How do I import my address data into that program?

If it helps, I am already a user of Gmail and Google Drive.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail merge can accept the address data directly from the .CSV file.